# Decoding url received by imaplib (python)

Tags: python, encoding, imap, imaplib

I receive e-mail by imaplib and python

```
        for i in self.mail_ids:
            status, data = self.mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')

            for response_part in data:
                if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                    message = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1])
                    mail_from = message['from']
                    mail_subject = message['subject']

                    mail_content = ''

                    for part in message.get_payload():
                        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                            mail_content += part.get_payload()

                    self.getLink(mail_from, mail_subject, mail_content)
```

**getLink** function:

```
    def getLink(self, mail_from, mail_subject, body):
        if 'example.com' in mail_from:
            link = ''
            body = body.split('Verify Email:')
            if len(body) > 1:
                link = body[1].strip()

                return link
        else:
            return False
```

By some reason extracted link is slightly different than in mail client (Outlook for example). The link that I get in my code doesn't work.

The link that I get in my code:

```
https://example.com/ls/click?upn=3DqDOo8cnwIoKzt0aLL1cB=eFE1RlVCKJFF5zAq8ml-2BFh1dq-2FeX22E9yMPFmLMSO5CYTzSd1xMk9MtbIUZ-2FN8zqptI4f=iEFGPw-2BGr9x7uoMLy3EVPfDeoqL1OGwYnFm-2BH1NOmPbKbWo938mh4OS3YQnUwjIoOBjbc0E=RkF4sQCc4jmTuKXt55J8OBB4CVPzXo34wS01-2F1ilD5QQNXxJX4rN-2Blj30Cy0ohAeSWNcMwg=mY2U-3DpF31_9c2oK9PLVNBgdL2e9tVxnFftogPOqJDcLMv2RpvpTAeLyVIxuc3QsTvymWx7TFw=kpVR1yRyC-2Bkmj1nr334KrMhPJkvQSiTX-2Fl7eTJ4OOpqJItVQlZVLhYPATdTpK2Ot1vpkPuP=-2FqEqLoPtUR-2B2Zz7l2tX643DxghB-2BII-2F9Xgoill6DRV2dXmNBfB08Ckm-2BX2BvVwOUR=XGNjmItOPc26LtQiUxNSo9SrlDtIG13VnTEY6uI0eMexJ8o-2FX5pjsbFE7wXeoqHoCDDwCW506=tkC1KQ-3D-3D
```

The link that I can see in mail client

```
https://example.com/ls/click?upn=qDOo8cnwIoKzt0aLL1cBeFE1RlVCKJFF5zAq8ml-2BFh1dq-2FeX22E9yMPFmLMSO5CYTzSd1xMk9MtbIUZ-2FN8zqptI4fiEFGPw-2BGr9x7uoMLy3EVPfDeoqL1OGwYnFm-2BH1NOmPbKbWo938mh4OS3YQnUwjIoOBjbc0ERkF4sQCc4jmTuKXt55J8OBB4CVPzXo34wS01-2F1ilD5QQNXxJX4rN-2BpXij-2FxSdxgJ5uPKUUjpnwI-3D6Lk-_9c2oK9PLVNBgdL2e9tVxnFftogPOqJDcLMv2RpvpTAeLyVIxuc3QsTvymWx7TFwkpVR1yRyC-2Bkmj1nr334KrMiviHq0Teci7yW5a-2Fd19VVcBVkfckYFgSu9I-2BoHCd0f-2FZdhRlxoyBKuQ89gKpVyRb-2BP1ERDa-2BWFaxZFVXnGy7xxQjG0P1rH1dx43M19aH5vKXPP8e0UMx6Hy3sdsFwDoqj-2FQ2xYSYmR335iD4uQJF-2Fs7k3xudsY-2FLg9kuev5flyobIOSslOjG-2BpyQMVVC84G4w-3D-3D
```

What may cause this difference and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Your body is [Quoted-Printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoded.

Use a policy argument that will do decoding for you:

```
email.message_from_bytes(x, policy=email.policy.default).
```

For backwards compatibility purposes, the default policy does not do content type decoding for you, and will leave the Quoted-Printable intact, making every = into an =3D, as you see in your link.

Alternatively, you can also try `part.get_payload(decode=true)`, which should also do the decoding for you.